# C memory allocation using up more bytes than is on the computer?

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, ram

The other day I created a C program on an Ubuntu virtual machine that was designed to waste as much memory as possible (just for fun). The code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
   unsigned long i = 0;
   while(1) {
      malloc(16711568);
      i++;
      printf("Iteration %lu: %lu total bytes allocated", i, i * 16711568);
   }
}
```

I am allocating 16711568 bytes at a time, as that is supposedly the maximum for malloc (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.2?topic=functions-malloc-reserve-storage-block). This code continues to run until about 35000 iterations (it changes every time) and roughly 5 trillion bytes are allocated. The issue is that according to the Ubuntu System Monitor, there are only 3.8 GiBs of memory on the system, and that when my program claimed to have used up trillions of bytes, the System Monitor only showed around 3 GiBs as having been used. Either my program or the System Monitor is wrong - and why? I'm new to all this malloc stuff :P

I tried rerunning the program several times, but the issue persisted. I double checked my code, but there don't seem to be any errors. I have no idea what's going on

Comment: Over 3G of swap space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: Virtual memory. It won't actually be allocated unless you write to it (on a page-by-page basis) - just reserved.

Comment: "and roughly 5 trillion bytes are allocated" How would you know if you do not check whether `malloc` actually returned any memory? Your "counter" changes every time because you just calculate the number but that doesn't mean that you got any memory.

Comment: "This code continues to run until about 35000 iterations" what happens afterwards?

Comment: The search term you want is "optimistic memory allocation". Oversimplified, no memory is actually allocated until you use the memory, i.e. write something to it. And if you do want to write something, you should write at least one byte in every 4096 byte block of memory.

Comment: @Gerhardh A message prints that says "Killed". Apparently that's what Linux does to programs when not enough resources are available.

Comment: @user3386109 If no memory is actually used, then how come my system resources got eaten up so quickly?

Comment: The resource that gets used up is the virtual memory page tables.